# A lot of buttons that does the same thing to be more neat?

Tags: android

I am making android application and I have the screen with text and under that I have 2 buttons. Like and Comment. I have many texts so I am thinking how can I make this with less lines of codes. Asking from guys who has more experience than me :)

Here is the picture how I have done it.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZE4T.png]

This is side thing: I want to update the buttons color and picture. I have done it in updateButtons method.

Comment: You can use a `ListView` if your `TextView` and two `Button` layout is repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with less code using for loop with parent layout of buttons. Upload your xml layout code, so I can describe in a good way.

Comment: Yes, correct. As you said, if you have only this much fix xml layout and you know it will never change then whatever you did that is correct way. You can just reduce your code of view injection by using any library like: butterknife.